# Storing large decimal numbers in Java

Tags: java

I need to store 17774132 in a double format, 
but it seems that double is to small since I get 1.7774132E7.

How can I overcome this problem? I need some kind of primitive that can hold it with floating point.

Thank you

Comment: As the answers have pointed out, your representation is in scientific format; Your desired value is well within [range](http://tinyurl.com/cgnpp9).  As also noted, doubles are not exact, and `BigDecimal` should be used if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java if you want accurate calculations for large numbers with fractions, you should use java.math.BigDecimal class. The integer counterpart is java.math.BigInteger.

Also I think double can accomodate 17774132, it's just showing the value in something called as "E Notation" which a Scientific notation to denote numbers. Refer to this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 2):

Remeber that means 1.7774132 * 10^7, so the value is represented by:

1.7774132 * 10000000

That's a big number, don't you think?

Java outputs by default on [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) if needed. Big numbers like that are expressed in scientific notation.

Comment: The value isn't represented like that inside, only when you convert to String like that. Inside, it is represented by a normalized fraction and a *binary* exponent.

Answer (score 1):

1.7774132E7 is exactly the same as 17774132. It's just displayed in [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). A `double` is more than capable of holding this value. As others have said, though, use `BigDecimal` if you're worried about size or accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

First, hopefully you recognize the [issues](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) with floating-point decimal representations.

`17774132` is equivalent to `1.7774132E7`; the "E7" means it is being multiplied by `10^7`.  If your issue is that you want it *displayed* differently, you can use a [NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Note that `17774132` is actually an integer and well below the threshold of ~2.1 billion for the `int` primitive type.  The `long` primitive type lets you go even higher if you are actually using integers.

If you want to *represent* the number differently and it is not an integer, you can try [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (or [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for legitimate integers too big for a long).