# float and double data type in mysql not storing the full digits required for my java program

Tags: java, mysql, floating-point, double, decimal

I'm storing some values in my mysql database using my java swing app but it doesn't store the full amount of the inputted number. For example if I use float as the data type for the column of the mysql database, it only store 6 digits, if I put in 123456.56, it would only store 123456.00 or if I input 12345.67 it would store only 12345.60. Same when I changed the data type of mysql to double it only stores 8 digits, so if I input 1234567.89 it would only store 1234567.90 only and it would round up the 8th digit. What's wrong with my coding? Thanks. I would like to store the full amount in the database such as millions and hundreds of thousands, ex. 12345678.55 or 445874.44 in full without it turning it into an exponent amount or cutting it short. How do I do that?

```
if(source == btn_confirm)
        {
            dbconnect connect = new dbconnect();

            String page = text_page.getText();
            String line = text_line.getText();
            String refpage = text_refpage.getText();
            String refline = text_refline.getText();
            String transaction_date = text_transdate.getText();
            String description = text_desc.getText();
            String account_code = text_accountcode.getText();
            String code_type = text_codetype.getText();
            String issue_date = text_issuedate.getText();
            String amount = text_amount.getText();

            System.out.println(amount);

            try
            {
                connect.addTransaction(page, line, refpage, refline, transaction_date, description, account_code, code_type, issue_date, amount);
                connect.close();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                System.out.println(x);
            }

            text_page.setText("");
            text_line.setText("");
            text_refpage.setText("");
            text_refline.setText("");
            text_transdate.setText("");
            text_desc.setText("");
            text_accountcode.setText("");
            text_codetype.setText("");
            text_issuedate.setText("");
            text_amount.setText("");

            text_page.requestFocus();
        }
```

the text_amount is the textfield containing the number to be passed to a string amount. string used to be a float but I opted to use a string instead as I thought it wouldn't make much of a difference when passing it into a sql statement. I used to use parsefloat.

the method addTransaction adds a transaction to the mysql database as so:

```
 public void addTransaction(String page, String line, String refpage, String refline, String transaction_date, String description, String account_code, String code_type, String issue_date, String amount) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        connect();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("insert into transaction (page, line, refpage, refline, transaction_date, description, account_code, code_type, issue_date, amount) values ('" + page + "', '" + line + "', '" + refpage + "', '" + refline + "', '" + transaction_date + "', '" + description + "', '" + account_code + "', '" + code_type + "','" + issue_date + "', " + amount + ")");
        System.out.println("Inserted transaction of page: " + page + " and line: " + line);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it is truncated -- Show us the code that receives the data and displays shortened results, together with all declarations, both in Java and MySQL.

Comment: edited the question for your review.

Comment: What is the declaration of `text_amount`?  Is it `float` or `Float` or something else?

Comment: Text_amount is a text field

Comment: And what is the "datatype" of `amount` in the table?  There are multiple places where conversions could be happening; we need to identify them in order to answer your Question.

Comment: Right now amount is set to decimal(12,2) in my mysql table.

Answer (score 1):

`FLOAT` has only 24 bits of precision.  That equates to about 7 decimal digits.  So, it is impossible to store more than what you are seeing.

`FLOAT(12,2)` has no use that I can figure.  It rounds twice -- once to decimal, once to binary.  Either use `DECIMAL(12,2)` or plain `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.

`DOUBLE` gives you about 16 digits of precision.  Again, don't use `(m,n)` with it, and don't expect more digits that it can hold in 53 *bits*.

MySQL can handle 65 decimal digits:  `DECIMAL(65, ...)`.  It is, however *fixed* in that you specify a constant number of places after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

How have you initialized the column? If you're storing as float, you can store it in the following format -  FLOAT(M,D) where M is the total number of digits and D is the number of digits after the decimal point.

If you have already created your table and don't want to lose information already stored in it, then you can modify the column type with the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ALTER COLUMN columnName FLOAT(M,D);
```

Replace, M and D accordingly.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html)

Comment: where do I initialize or implement this? I use mysql workbench there's no function to initialize or input M or D. Thanks.

Comment: When you create your table, you have define each column, in the column type enter FLOAT(M,D) and replace M and D according to your needs. If this doesn't work, then your swing app may not be passing the entire number.

Comment: thanks I found it in alter table and changed the values in data type.. yes you are correct my Java swing app is not passing the entire number and converts it to exponent and cuts it in the 8th digit.  I use amount = Float.parseFloat(text_amount.getText()); to convert my textfield number to a float, is there a way to correct this?

Comment: This is yet another argument for never using `(M,D)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.

Comment: As Rick James said, FLOAT or DOUBLE should not be used to store large values in the above format. 

[Check out the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676521/storing-large-decimal-numbers-in-java)

You should probably store your values in BigDecimal.

Comment: I've set Float to (12,2) but it still rounds up to the 7th digit.

Comment: The issue is in your Java side, not MySQL. You should use BigDecimal. Check my previous comment.

Comment: I've checked the java side it's passing the correct number. Just a question though, there is no bigdecimal data type in mysql, just decimal.

Comment: It's ok I've solved it, I changed the data type in Mysql to Deciman(12,2) it seems to work. Thanks.