# How to store long decimal numbers in Java

Tags: java

I have a code in java that says,

```
btmpW / imgW
```

but in this case I get `0` as the value, I tried using `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` as my data type but it still returns `0`.

When I try to do the `Log.i()` on both int values, I got this

```
I/btmpW: 548
I/imgW: 1041
```

So using a calculator to calculate, I got `0.5346341463`... and I am new to Java, but I think Java don't accept numbers with more than 9 digits, making me assume that Java returns only the `(int)0` and since the digits are more than 9, it just ignored the decimal. So i searched and found something like `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`. So I tried to use them, but I am getting some errors

So I want to know, is there a way to store such value in Java. `btmpW` and `imgW` are user defined so I don't know what the outcome would be when I run `btmpW / imgW`, so basically, is there a digits data type in Java that stores both long, short, integer and decimal numbers

### Update

Below are the errors I am getting

```
BigDecimal a = (BigDecimal)btmpW / imgW;  //Inconvertibles types; cannot cast 'int' to java.math.BigDecimal

BigInteger a = (BigInteger)btmpW / imgW;  //Inconvertibles types; cannot cast 'int' to java.math.BigInteger

BigIntegers a = (BigIntegers)btmpW / imgW;  //Inconvertibles types; cannot cast 'int' to java.math.BigIntegers

BigDecimal a = btmpW / imgW;  //Inconvertibles types; REQUIRED: BigDecimal FOUND int

BigInteger a = btmpW / imgW;  //Inconvertibles types; REQUIRED: BigInteger FOUND int

BigIntegers a = btmpW / imgW;  //Inconvertibles types; REQUIRED: BigIntegers FOUND int
```

Comment: `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`. You should tell us what you tried. But first try searching for the errors. And if you need help, tell us what the errors are. Best of luck!

Comment: `So I tried to use them, but I am getting some errors` - you might be on right track. What errors are you facing? Floating point numbers by nature doesn't limit you to number of digits after decimal point but depends on mantisa (IEEE-754)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing large decimal numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676521/storing-large-decimal-numbers-in-java)

Comment: I have updated my question, to show the errors

Comment: Java does **not** have operator overloading. Try [`BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-). `BigDecimal a = btmpW.divide(imgW);` - next, you cannot **cast** primitive values to a `BigDecimal` (and even if you could, they would not magically gain more precision that way). Instead, you should refer to the **JavaDoc**. You probably want to use the constructor [`BigDecimal(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.lang.String-) (since you have user input).

Comment: @Nitin no it doesn't, because I have tried using `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` but it throws errors

Comment: @Elliott tried `BigDecimal a = btmpW.divide(imgW);` but I get error saying `can't resolve the method 'divide'`

Comment: @KANAYOAUGUSTINUG And **what** type is `btmpW`? And where did you get it? Because it's **not** a `BigDecimal`. And I don't think you read all of my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this trick got it working... I had to change my `int` values to `double`, and worked with `double` instead

**Initial code**

```
int imgW = imageView.getWidth();
int btmpW = bitmap.getWidth();
```

**Final code**

```
double imgW = imageView.getWidth();
double btmpW = bitmap.getWidth();
double a = btmpW / imgW;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int btmpW = 548;
int imgW = 1041;

BigDecimal btm = new BigDecimal(btmpW);
BigDecimal img = new BigDecimal(imgW);

System.out.println(img.divide(btm, MathContext.DECIMAL128));
```

**Output:**
1.899635036496350364963503649635036

**Reference**:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-java.math.MathContext-

**For more about MathContext**: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/java_math_mathcontext.htm

Comment: I don't really like `new BigDecimal(int)` here. It's not really wrong, but I'm assuming OP is dealing with user input in some way. And reading in an `int` is not going to allow OP to store more precision than an `int` on input. Which is why I was trying to point OP at `new BigDecimal(String)`.

Comment: `MathContext.DECIMAL128` is throwing an error... I don't know why, but I am writing my code on Android Studio platform

Comment: `import java.math.MathContext;` and Google before you ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert those tow numbers in BigDecimal first. I'm not sure what type does your numbers have, but if it's String, primitive (e.g. int, double) or primitive wrapper (e.g. Integer, Double) you could try to convert them directly as follow:

```
BigDecimal dbBtmpW = new BigDecimal(btmpW);
BigDecimal dbImgW = new BigDecimal(imgW);
```

After that you could use divide method to do your operation, unfortunately Java doesn't support operator overloading, so you have to call the specific method:

```
BigDecimal result = dbBtmpW.divide(dbImgW);
```

I hope this it'll help you.

Comment: No, it does not work. It through an exception Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result. We will need to add MathContext